# Are back-end routes fulfilled when the URL matches the route path or when a fetch request is made from the front-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

What is the difference between making a request via a fetch API and making a request by just navigating to the URL that matches the route path?

For example, if I have a backend route like this:

```
let ALL_RESTAURANTS = [
  { id: "0b65fe74-03a9-4b37-ab09-1c8d23189273", name: "Taco Express" },
  { id: "869c848c-7a58-4ed6-ab88-72ee2e8e677c", name: "Pho Vinason" },
  { id: "213ca4a4-97ce-4783-917b-f94ef8315778", name: "Rondo Japanese" },
  { id: "2334b925-802e-4161-b5dd-de53315c9325", name: "SpiceBox Indian Food" },
  { id: "3e075c8e-7489-4fb6-b029-43a0a1b8936c", name: "Dick's Burgers" },
  { id: "e8036613-4b72-46f6-ab5e-edd2fc7c4fe4", name: "Fremont Bowl Sushi" },
  { id: "7f4a4fe2-58eb-4833-9e93-2dfdd1a1d91f", name: "Cafe Turko" },
];

app.get('/restaurants', (req, res) => {
    res.json(ALL_RESTAURANTS);
});
```

Let's say I have a fetch API on the frontend like so:

```
const getRestaurants = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/restaurants`);
  const restaurants = await response.json();

  return restaurants;
};
```

If I navigate to "/restaurants", won't the backend fetch all the restaurants from the `ALL_RESTAURANTS` array? If that's the case, then what is the point of the fetch API?

Comment: If you navigate to `/restaurants` you'll display the JSON in the browser. Most users don't want to see JSON, they want HTML web pages. APIs are used internally by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By navigating to url you effectively have your browser make a GET request. Browser is fetching data from your backend for you. If you navigate to a website url, the HTML document is sent in response; if it is an API endpoint you will most likely receive a json response. Either way the full request -response cycle is being completed.

Reading data from an array in your example would be the equivalent of a database query performed by your server based on informations in your request (route and method at minimum, possibly additional parameters like restaurants serving certain type of food or in certain localization).

You have no way of making any other type of request like PUT, POST or DELETE by just navigating to url. You cannot set custom headers nor send json body. You will not trigger preflight request. You can still pass query params in the url and browser will attatch cookies though.

Depending on the CORS settings of the server, you may not even be able to display json in the browser.

You rarely aim to present the data in json format, usually you want to parse and handle it in some way: use markup to show data in a readable form (a list of restaurants for example). You may want to display data based on condition or handle possible errors.

Navigating to an API endpoint will, in the best case scenario, return a hard-to-read string. HTTP response, depending on chosen format, may contain some meta data like response status, status code and so on. Most of the times you don't want to show that to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just have one other question. If you don't want the data to be presented in JSON format, what's preventing that from happening if you navigate to the API endpoint? Would I have to make it so the fetch API is automatically called whenever that URL is reached?

Comment: @BrunoOliveira There are multiple approaches. If that route is designated only for your JSON data, you can redirect all "GET" requests away from that endpoint or present a 404 page. Then retrieve the data via a "POST" request. This works because when a user navigates to the endpoint, their browser it performs a "GET" request which your server can route it away from the JSON data but when you make a "POST" request via fetch, your backend server is able to handle the request correctly.

Comment: You could also secure the endpoints with a token and have your app send it in a header whenever fetching data, that would give you application level authorization.